# php relative path not found

Tags: lamp, server-side-includes

I'm migrating to a new server.

Before I could use: `include/XXXX.php` in `/var/site/test.php`.

Now I have use: `/var/site/include/XXXX.php`

I'm using:

Ubuntu 10.4
Apache2
PHP5

Comment: What did `phpinfo();` say your `include_path` was before? What does it say it is now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the include_path in either your application or in the php.ini file. This is often in /etc/php.ini or /usr/local/etc/php.ini.